# Does Ubuntu damage some LCD screens?

Tags: graphics, display

I have an Acer Aspire 5732 Z, with 4 GB RAM and Pentium(R) Dual-core 2.20 GHz Processor. My graphics card is: Mobile Intel® 4 Series.

I had been using Windows since 2013, then I decided to use Ubuntu last summer (June 2015). So, I installed Ubuntu (and removed Windows 7). And I enjoyed Ubuntu for about four months (December 2015).

One day, Ubuntu started showing a low-graphics mode error... I tried to log in to my account using the command line. It says that I logged in successfully while asking me again to enter my password and username... This happened endlessly.

So, as all my work data was on GitHub, I decided to format my computer, and I installed Windows 7 again.

After working with Windows 7 for less than a month, my LCD screen started to show vertical lines (that increase in intensity over time), and nothing shows up on the screen. This never happened until I switched to Ubuntu and switched back to Windows 7 again.

So, I started using desktop screens (with a VGA cable) for about two months, then I changed the LCD display of my laptop, and it's fixed and working great now.

But, I still want to use Ubuntu. Could the LCD problem be caused by Ubuntu (or at least a specific configuration in it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is physically impossible for an operating system to damage the LCD.

Most likely the problem was that the LCD's ribbon cable had a loose connection to the motherboard.

Either that or the display died on its own...

Comment: So, thank you ... the guy who fixed the computer told me that the problem was the LCD display itself... it's working anymore.

But, how can I fix this Low-Graphics mode error?

Comment: I really want to install ubuntu, but I'm afraid it's possible to encounter this error again.

Comment: @SmootQ - Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site, not a forum. Therefore I would ask you to post it as a separate question.

Comment: Dont be so sure. Seems there is a problem with linux core 5.19.12. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/linux-kernel-update-kills-laptop-displays

Comment: @codelovesme Wow, that's crazy.... This answer was posted many years before that bug, though.

Comment: Nobody says that this damage is occurring because of that bug. But it supports the proposition that software can give irreversible damage to hardware and it means that the accepted answer is invalid. Just think about it next time before trying to insult people. @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit